# Unable to add cassandra connection

Tags: cassandra, wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am trying to add an connection to my cassandra database.

As shown in the examples I added this definition:

```
@Store(type='cassandra', column.family='StockTable',keyspace='AnalyticsFamily',cassandra.host='localhost')
@IndexBy('volume')
@PrimaryKey('symbol')
define table StockTable (symbol string, price float, volume long);
```

In the editor I get an red cross as shown in the image below.
Am I missing the cassandra driver on the worker? If yes, how can I add it to the docker image? Or what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the osgi compatible cassandra connectors to {SP_HOME}/lib folder.

Please see https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP4xx/Configuring+Datasources for more details